# Are there any working methods for debugging my iOS app without Mac?

Tags: ios, debugging, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic for developing mobile apps. I have bought the developer license and installed my app on my phone but for some reason i can only see a blank screen. For debugging i would need a Mac computer, but unfortunately i don't have any and remote desktop also won't works because i need to connect my phone via usb.

I am really disappointed and i need to finish my app for my university thesis but Apple just can't let me do that. I would be really happy if anyone could help me because i tried some method with google, but i could only debug websites not my app.

Comment: Hackintosh? Yeah apples not really a developer’s best friend

Comment: While OSX was Mavericks, I installed VMware on my win-PC and installed Mavericks on it - SW based Hackintosh. It worked nicely w/ my iphone connected via USB. However, when I upgraded to Yosemite, it got very slow and nearly useless. Not sure how nice/bad with your PC and High Sierra, though.

Comment: @beshio, I have 8GB ram installed and High Sierra works fair on my machine.

Comment: That's good to know. My PC was fairly old and I ended up building HW based Hackintosh.